# python print utf-8 character stored in unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm reading pickle file retrieved from some library. there were a lot of utf-8 characters stored in **unicode** string. For example:

```
u'\xc4\x91' #đ
u'\xc3\xad' #í
u'\xc3\u017d' #�\u017d
...
```

I can encode and display most of them using `raw_unicode_escape` 
However all the characters with `\u` escape like the third one above are not displayed properly: `�\u017d`. How can I fix that? 
**EDIT:**
Each string above should be a character

**EDIT 2: The code I use to read the file**

```
model_dir = '../../projects/python/test/model-5'
with open(model_dir, 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
seq = model.sequitur
rightI = seq.rightInventory
print repr(rightI.list)
```

the result contains something similar to above examples

Comment: What do you mean not properly? Could you make an example of that?

Comment: Maybe you have problems with console encoding? Try writing your output to file instead of stdout.

Comment: @LaurynasTamulevičius I just added according to your request

Comment: @damians I did try to write it to file, actually my original intention is to work through file, but it just doesn't work. There are a lot of utf-8 characters but only the ones wit `\u` got problem

Comment: Can you post an MCVE that doesn't work?

Comment: @Gribouillis I'm sorry but did you imply that you can somehow print the third string properly?

Comment: Oh yes on my bash terminal in kubuntu 16.04 it prints very well, there is no problem at all.

Comment: which method did you use to print? and the result pls

Comment: I simply type this in the python repl: `>>> print(u'\xc3\u017d')` and it prints `ÃŽ`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry to confuse you, the thing is, each codepoint there should be a character, I will edit the original post immediately

Comment: *Why* does the pickle file have mis-decoded UTF-8 in Unicode strings in the first place?  They should have been decoded as UTF-8 so there are the correct Unicode characters, or be UTF-8-encoded byte strings.

Comment: @MarkTolonen The library which this pickle file came from still can use it normally so I don't think it is mis-decoded or anything, however I just can't figure out what is wrong on my end

Comment: @AtheS21 if the library that uses this data is written in python, you could perhaps go see in the source code how the library unpickles the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps

```
PYTHONIOENCODING="utf8" python script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a unicode escape string. If you print it, and your console's font and encoding support it you will see the following:

```
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'UTF-8'
>>> i
[u'\xc4\x91', u'\xc3\xad', u'\xc3\u017d']
>>> for q in i:
...   print(q)
...
Ä
Ã­
ÃŽ
```

To make sure they are rendered (printed on the screen) properly, you need to make sure that:

- the encoding of the file is correct for the data that is entered in the file.
- the encoding and font of the terminal supports the glyphs

If you see � it means that the encoding declared for the application does not support that specific code point, so the system does not know how to render it.

Comment: You may have misunderstood me. When I said I have utf-8 character stored in unicode string, I mean it should be `'\xc4\x91'` (without prefix u) but after  loaded from the pickle, they turn out to be unicode, so in order to print them right, I had to convert them back to str using `encode(raw_unicode_escape)`. And I can guarantee the terminal is able to display that character, I just think the encoding is messed up somewhere.

Comment: @ATheS21 then you made an incorrect conversion. It's not what you should have done.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is about the encoding of file names on the system. It could be different from input/output encoding. There is also `sys.stdout.encoding`.

Comment: @Gribouillis can you elaborate? When I found out all those characters are in unicode and couldn't print them, I searched around and found that [raw_unicode_escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182716/python-unicode-string-with-utf-8) solution and it works in most case. I don't really understand it that well

Comment: @ATheS21  From the doc, `raw_unicode_escape` is used to create a string that you can use in python code as a unicode *literal*. It's very specific to python source code. The real problem here is that we don't know where your data comes from. Did you read a pickled file without the pickle module, or is it an unpickled object that yields these strings? Do you know which unicode code points correspond to your data? The best thing to do is to explain how you got the data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I did unpickle the file to get the string so the data should be in their original form. the `u\xc3\u017d` should be printed as 'ô' which is `c3b4` according to the [utf-8 tool](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C3%B4&mode=char). I don't know why I get the `\u017d` instead but pickle should not get me the wrong data right? And all of the other character is displayed correctly as well

Comment: @AtheS21 A good idea is to print the `repr()` of  the original data, and also give the lines of code that produced the u'\xc3\u017d'.

Comment: I added the code used to read the file, thank you for helping me on this